# (SOLVED)The Application Gives Error When Opened from Recent Applications

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity, android-lifecycle

There is a **SplashActivity** in my application, the application is started with this activity. **SplashActivity** has a duration of 2.5 seconds, when this time is completed, **HomeActivity** opens. When the back button is pressed in the **HomeActivity**, the application is exited with finishAffinity(). Whenever I exit **HomeActivity** and then click on my application again from recent applications, the application cannot restart itself. I get user information in **SplashActivity** and give it to **HomeActivty** and I use **Firebase** for this.

The error it gives when the application cannot start itself is as follows:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.medita.mobile/com.medita.mobile.SplashActivity}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.

How can I fix this? I want the application to restart itself with SplashActivity when I exit HomeActivity by pressing the back button and click on the application again from the recent applications section.

I tried closing the activity by deleting it from the recent apps when closing it (finishAndRemoveTask()) but nothing worked. Therefore I think that everything ends with SplashActivity. Also I tried finishAffinity() in onStop() onPause() methods but it didn't work too.

My manifest file;

```
<activity
          android:name=".HomeActivity"
          android:exported="false"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
<activity
          android:name=".SplashActivity"
          android:exported="true"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

SplashActivity;

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    private DatabaseReference currentUserRef;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    String username = null;
    String email = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        ...

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (currentUser != null) {
                    getLoggedInUsername();
                    Intent home = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    overridePendingTransition(0,R.anim.fade_out);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    SplashActivity.this.finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0,R.anim.fade_out);
                }

            }
        }, 2500);

    }

   private String getLoggedInUsername() {
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        ...

        return username;
    }
}
```

HomeActivtiy;

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity();
}
```

**This is how I solved my problem;**

I added this code to my SplashActivity.

```
static {
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); }
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`? Does it work that way?

Comment: no, unfortunately, it didn't work but I solved it, I will edit my question. thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom `Application` class (a class that `extends Application`). In the `onCreate()` of your custom `Application` class, perform your Firebase initialization and configuration. This method gets called only once, when your application is started, before any activities are instantiated.

Remove the Firebase initialization from your `Activity`.

Add your custom `Application` class to your manifest in the `<application>` declaration like this:

```
android:name="my.package.MyCustomApplication" (or whatever you call your custom Application class)
```

Note: You can also remove the code in `HomeActivity.onBackPressed()`, as the default implementation of `onBackPressed()` will finish the current `Activity` and you only have one `Activity` active at this time.

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but it didn't work for me, I added setPersistenceEnabled(true) as static in my SplashActivity. thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, it should work. What do you mean "it didn't work"?

Comment: Anyway, glad you were able to solve the problem.